# Should I always use dynamic sql when programatically use some stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I have a stored procedure that can get the number of records in a table, in which the `@tableName` is the parameter of the stored procedure. Let's call it  `FastCount`:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(object_id), SUM(row_count) AS rows
FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(@tableName)
  AND index_id < 2
GROUP BY OBJECT_NAME(object_id);
```

Now, let's say I have 50 tables, like data_1950, data_1951, .....data_2000. I wrote a batch, query each table's records count, and put them into a temporary table. It works like a charm

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
    TableName varchar(30), 
    RecordsCount int
)

DECLARE @sql as varchar(max)
DECLARE @yearN as int = 1950
DECLARE @tbName as sysname

WHILE @yearN <= 2000
BEGIN
    SET @tbName = QUOTEName(N'[dbo].data_' + Convert(varchar,@yearN))
    SET @sql = N'Exec [dbo].FastCount @tableName=' + @tbName

    INSERT INTO #Temp 
        EXEC (@sql)
    SET @yearN = @yearN + 1
END

SELECT * FROM #Temp

DROP TABLE #Temp
```

However, if I replace the dynamic SQL string part

```
SET @sql = N'Exec [dbo].FastCount @tableName=' + @tbName

INSERT INTO #Temp 
    EXEC (@sql)
```

with a straightforward call

```
INSERT INTO #Temp 
    EXEC [dbo].FastCount @tableName = @tbName
```

Then the whole batch just not work...

So I don't understand why... Should I always use dynamic SQL string and `exec(@sql)` when programmatically using the stored procedure. A big thanks for taking the time to look.

Comment: If you don't need immediate accuracy you can get a table's approximate rowcount from `sys.partitions`. guessing not much is happening in your 1950s table. What does 'just not work' actually mean?

Comment: What is the data type of the @tableName parameter?  And yes, as Stu mentions, you should provide more detail about what "just not work" means - no results?  Error message?

Comment: @Stu Yes, you can assume this batch will only execute when no one is writing into the tables.   If I replace the @sql=N'....' exec(@sql) with a direct call exec... no error shows, but no results returned

Comment: I don't get it: your first query without the `where` will get exactly what you want, no temp tables or dynamic SQL needed. I question the legitimacy of a design with a new table for each year though, should just be one big table

Comment: @Craig not work simply means no results show. While work shows the result table which is table and the number of records in each table; tableName is just varchar

Comment: Fyi, when you aren't quoting your dynamic object properly (with `QUOTENAME`) you arr making a huge injection issue.

Comment: I fail to see like @Charlieface why you need this elaborate process - you can simply insert your counts directly from the system tables and if necessary join to `sys.tables` to filter on the table name(s)

Comment: You try to implement procedural logic with loops and all that stuff within SQL, which is designed to work with *datasets* in *declarative* way, so you are on a wrong way. If you really need this to be wrapped with procedure, then you can use input parameter of [type table](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15) and join with it inside procedure. But for this particular case it is not required at all, just simple select with `in` predicate.

Comment: @Charlieface - my assumption is that the OP's first query is the actual statement inside the stored proc

Comment: For row source you can call `exec` directly with named parameters. Check this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017l&fiddle=cbf5765e729c85f8e9cdf09edd7628d2)

Comment: @Craig I copy paste your `Insert Into #Temp Exec [dbo].FastCount @tableName = CONVERT(varchar(255), @tbName)` and comment out the `@sql=...... Insert Into #Temp Exec(@sql)`, it says Incorrect syntax near Convert on the line I pasted

Comment: Oh - my bad.  Don't worry about that for now.  I'll test something, since I want to answer your specific question about why the non-dynamic SQL was not working

Comment: @Craig Thank you!, I think this will help lots of SQL newbies like me.

Comment: @Charlieface You are right, the first query without where can give me all the tables info.  My real question actually is not about how to achieve this actually.  BTW, I use where actually give the flexibility to this SP, and then I can use this SP to count whatever table in the database, not necessary all the tables

Comment: Bad idea: always work set-based. If you are going to need results for multiple tables then write a new stored procedure that can do that. This applies to all kinds of stored procedures: don't run them in a loop, write them so that they can do everything in one go

Comment: @Charlieface Oh, thanks. That's good to know. good to know this SQL 'philosophy'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, here is what is happening in the two scenarios that you posed in your original question.  (Yes, the reality is that there are probably better ways to achieve your end result, but let's look at the actual problem that you posed .... why is the behaviour of your INSERT / EXEC different, depending on how you made the call).

First, you have your variable declared, that will contain your table name:

```
DECLARE @tbName as sysname
```

Then you have your looping block that incrementally increases the year number, to generate the different table names.  There's nothing inherently wrong with the looping block, so let's just look at an example using one of the table names, to see what's happening within the WHILE block.  Take the first table name as the example, which would be [dbo].data_1950.

Your statement:

```
set @tbName = QUOTEName(N'[dbo].data_' + Convert(varchar,@yearN))
```

ultimately takes the string "[dbo].data_1950" - which comes from concatenating '[dbo].data_' with the year number (in this case, 1950) converted to a string (varchar) - and passes it to the QUOTENAME() function.  The QUOTENAME() function takes its input and a second parameter, which is the character that the input should be quoted with (if the 2nd parameter is not passed, then the default is []).  Thus, if we then converted the @tbName variable to a string, it would appear like this:

```
[[dbo].data_1950]
```

Now we get to see the funky way that SQL deals with "sysname" data-types.  (In fact, as you read further down, maybe the issue is not primarily tied to the "sysname" data-type, but anyhow, take away from this what you will).  To be honest, "sysname" is, in itself, a little bit of a funky data-type anyway, which I tend to steer away from, unless absolutely necessary.  But anyhow, on to the details of the issue that you were seeing.

Step 1 - I created a version of your stored proc, but I included a statement that would output the value of the @tableName parameter that was passed in.  This gives us an opportunity to see what SQL is doing in the two different scenarios, and then explain why the results are different.

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].FastCount
(
    @tableName varchar(100)
)
AS
BEGIN
    PRINT @tableName;

    SELECT OBJECT_NAME(object_id), SUM(row_count) AS rows
    FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats
    WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(@tableName)
    AND index_id < 2
    GROUP BY OBJECT_NAME(object_id);
END
```

Step 2 - our first scenario is executing the dynamic SQL.

```
set @tbName = QUOTEName(N'[dbo].data_' + Convert(varchar,@yearN))
set @sql = N'Exec [dbo].FastCount @tableName=' + @tbName
Insert Into #Temp Exec(@sql)
```

Now, we know that the @tbName variable contains

```
[[dbo].data_1950]
```

and therefore we can then infer that the @sql variable contains

```
Exec [dbo].FastCount @tableName=[[dbo].data_1950]
```

so that is effectively the statement that is executed by the Exec(@sql) command.

When this runs, and we look at the output of the PRINT command, we see

```
[dbo].data_1950
```

and we see a result from our query (the table name and row count).  This makes sense, of course, because our table name is "data_1950", and the schema of the table is "dbo", so the SELECT statement to get the row count is going to work as expected.

Step 3 - run the EXEC command directly, without the use of the @sql variable, ie.

```
Insert Into #Temp Exec [dbo].FastCount @tableName = @tbName
```

Now, when we look at the output of the PRINT command for this execution of the "FastCount" stored procedure, we see

```
[[dbo].data_1950]
```

Of course, this is now NOT going to produce the results that we expect, because we're telling SQL to find the row count for a table named "[dbo].data_1950" (in the absence of the specific schema, SQL will just assume the default schema.  In this case, with a schema of [dbo], we'd be telling SQL to get the row count from a table named [dbo].[[dbo].data_1950] - which is clearly NOT the table name).

You should see the obvious difference - in one scenario, the parameter value that is passed into the stored is the "correct" reference to the table name, and in the other scenario it is not.

As a final step, let's look at how the "non-dynamic" SQL would be executed, to achieve the results that we need.  In this instance, there's no need for the QUOTENAME() function:

```
set @tbName = N'[dbo].data_' + Convert(nvarchar,@yearN)
Insert Into #Temp Exec [dbo].FastCount @tableName = @tbName
```

When we run it in this way, we see the expected output ([dbo].data_1950) from the PRINT command, and we see the expected query results (containing the table name and row count).

Can I explain this behaviour, exactly?  Errr, not necessarily ... maybe someone else will be able to explain specifically what is happening, and why.  My only interpretation is that when the EXEC() statement is passed the dynamic sql (ie. @sql variable) it is first interpreting the entire string and stripping out identifiers (in the case, the surrounding [] ... on what basis is it making that decision, I don't know).  As opposed to the non-dynamic execution, where the @tbName value ([[dbo].data_1950]) is just being passed straight in as the parameter, with no modification (and thus causing the unexpected end result that we saw).

Hopefully this information is useful to you (or, at least, to someone else in the future!).

Comment: OMG，You rock sir!!!       This is definitely the gold spirit of a good engineer. Always dig deeper and find the root cause of the problem---no matter how stupid the problem may be. Guys like you make the world better.  Thanks!!!

Comment: No problems.  So you should have two take-aways from this question that you asked - a) a tidbit of SQL know-how, from my answer, that you'll keep in the back of your mind and I'm sure need to call on at some point in the future, and b) hopefully a more elegant approach to your actual requirement from the answers and comments that others have made

Answer (score 0):

In general you should avoid dynamic SQL, and you should avoid granting rights to execute dynamic SQL, unless absolutely necessary. This is for performance and security reasons.

The typical way to deal with this situation is to use a [partitioned view](https://sqlsunday.com/2014/08/31/partitioned-views/):

```
CREATE VIEW DataView
AS
    SELECT '1950' TableName, * FROM Data_1950
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '1951' TableName, * FROM Data_1951
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '1952' TableName, * FROM Data_1952
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '1953' TableName, * FROM Data_1953
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '1954' TableName, * FROM Data_1954
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '1955' TableName, * FROM Data_1955
```

(Keep adding select statements until you have covered all of your tables.)

Now to get your table counts all you need to do is execute this:

```
SELECT TableName, COUNT(*) RecordCount
FROM DataView
GROUP BY TableName
```

Isn't that much easier?

Comment: Hi John WU, thanks for your suggestion.       I use loop because 1. there's a large number of tables years, 2. each table has huge number of records (300+M) ......So your method firstly I will have a long long script, secondly, it may very very slow.... And since I already have a stored procedure that can give me the record count of a large table quickly)... That leads me naturally to think to use a while loop to call the FastCount store to proc and then aggregate each count result into a temporary table.